# How to run pod as a global service in Kubernetes minion

Tags: kubernetes, coreos

In coreos we can defined service as

```
[X-Fleet]
Global=true
```

This will make sure that this particular service will run in all the nodes.

How do i achieve same thing for a pod in Kubernetes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you want to use [Daemonset](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.2/docs/design/daemon.md) - a way to run a daemon on every node in a Kubernetes cluster.